# $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

I know this question has already been answered in some posts on MSE but I am posting it to clear my doubt.

I have another reasoning for this question could someone please tell me whether I am correct;Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be topological spaces such that $X$ is subspace of $Y$ and $Y$ is subspace of $Z$.We know that if $Y$ is subspace of $Z$ and $X$ is subspace of $Y$ then $X$ is Subspace of $Z$.Now for $X$ to be compact in $Y$,it has to be compact under subspace topology induced by $Y$ but then $X$ is also subspace of Z and hence it has to be compact under subspace topology induced by $Z$.So for $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ to be compact in $\mathbb{Q}$ it is equivalent to say that it is compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$(since $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ with subspace topology of $\mathbb{Q}$ is same as subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$)  and hence we can used Heine Borel theorem now.Therefore $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, a subset of $\Bbb Q$ is compact in $\Bbb Q$ if and only if it is compact as a subset of $\Bbb R$

Comment: @Bonnaduck; thanks

Comment: "Closed" is a relative notion and a set is closed in a space. For instance, (assuming standard topologies), $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ is closed in $\Bbb Q$ but not in $\Bbb R$, even though they both induce the same topology on $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$. However, compact is independent of the ambient space, and "$X$ is compact in $Y$" makes little sense. "$X$ is compact" is enough (assuming the topology on $X$ is already established).

Comment: @Bonnaduck; so instead $\mathbb{Q}$ can I say in general a subset of set $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact in in$S$ iff it is compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ using the argument given by me in this post?

Comment: @Arthur; exactly I was thinking in same direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm: yes, compactness is "absolute" in that indeed if $K:=[0,1]\cap \Bbb Q$ were compact in $\Bbb Q$ it would also be compact in $\Bbb R$. And $K$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$ (its closure is $[0,1]\neq K$) so cannot be compact in $\Bbb R$ (compact implies closed in the space for *any* metric space; note that $K$ *is* closed in $\Bbb Q$ so we need to look in the reals for this to work).

But there are plenty of other "reasons" too, as you found in the other answers.

Comment: ,Thank you so much!